# Can you used AutoLayout in combination with UISplitViewController?

Tags: ios, iphone, uisplitviewcontroller, ios-autolayout

I have successfully created an app that runs on an iPhone (trait Compact width) which uses UISplitViewController to implement a menu on the lefthand side of the screen. It uses Storyboard extensively (with 23 Views/Units) together with AutoLayout. I am aiming for a functionality similar to the Gmail App and many others.

[image]

When the menu is visible in portrait mode it occupied 80% of the screen, leaving the Detail / Secondary View still visible but with only 20% of the screen. I achieved this using viewWillLayoutSubviews & viewWillTransitionToSize to set the splitViewController.preferredPrimaryColumnWidthFraction = 0.8;

The problem or side effect that is causing me grief, is that the Secondary views which all use AutoLayout have all their internal views buttons and labels squashed up and overlayed when the menu is being displayed.

[image]

So my question is this: is it possible to use AutoLayout within UISplitViewController without producing the squashed up effect? I'm sure it is, so what am I missing, what do I have to do to trick the AutoLayout system into not squashing up the layout, but instead just slide it out of view?

addendum:  In the above screenshot the Secondary View with the blue navigation bar is a SettingsTableViewController.m. This code did not contain any NSLayoutConstraints neither did the associated part of the Main.storyboard. Following the suggestion in the comments: I could not find any way, within the "Add New Contraint" pop-up menu of the Main.storyboard to select the superview to be able to add a "Equal Widths" constraint to the "Table View".

[image]

So as an alternative I added the following code to the viewDidLoad method in SettingsTableViewController.m, but it had no effect.

```
self.view.superview addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                                relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                   toItem:self.view.superview
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                               multiplier:1
                                                                 constant:0]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Not reduce width of main view. You should just shifting main view to the right.

Comment: How do I do that? Nowhere in my code do I directly set or change the width of the main view. It's width is set automatically as a consequence of the main = detail / secondary view being embedded within UISplitViewController.
How do I cause it to be shifted to the right?

Comment: @Steve, remove trailing constraint for main view, and make width main view equal(1:1) to superview

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I have tried it but without success. I have updated my question to explain what I did.